# Why does the CSS hover function work for the ".Footer" and not for the ".Left"? Please help me

Tags: html, css, hover

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TOM</title>
```

Why does the CSS hover function work for the ".Footer" and not for the ".Left"?. I can't see or figure out what is causing the problem. What is wrong with the code? Any help is greatly appreciated!

THE CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.Footer {
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.Footer:hover {
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.Left {
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.Left:hover {
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.Header {
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.H1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 440px;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.Footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 63px;
    width: 178px;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
}
.Container {
    background-color: #0F0;
    position: relative;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 1020px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.Left {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.Center {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.Right {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
```

SCRIPT (don't think it relavant)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/work_on.png','images/sketch_on.png','images/about_on.png')">
```

THE HTML:

```
<div class="Header">
  <div class="H1">
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('work','','images/work_on.png',1)">
      <img src="images/work_off.png" name="work" width="120" height="40" border="0" id="work" />
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('sketch','','images/sketch_on.png',1)">
      <img src="images/sketch_off.png" name="sketch" width="200" height="40" border="0" id="sketch" />
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" target="_self" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('about','','images/about_on.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      <img src="images/about_off.png" name="about" width="120" height="40" border="0" id="about" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Container">
  <img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330" class="Left"/>
  <img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330" class="Center" />
  <img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330" class="Right" />
</div>

<div class="Footer">
  <img src="images/tom_logo.png" width="178" height="63" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can't figure out what the difference is or what is causing the problem. Please help me, any help is very appreciated.Thank you.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mARcU/1/)

Comment: where is the `.Left` element

Comment: It's on the 6th line of HTML.  Scroll to the right a bit.

Comment: Have you tried this without the JavaScript?  That DreamWeaver imageswap script always makes me cringe, and as many times as I have seen it I've never been able to read it.  It's possible it's changing the code related to the image tag in such a way that the `.Left` class is no longer relevant.

Comment: You can make a web page using DreamWeaver or you can make a web page understanding what is going on. You can choose, but you must chooose. (ok, ok, I'm exagerating a  bit) BTW, you should try to create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `z-index: -1;` for `.container`. Remove it and it will work fine

```
.Container {
    background-color: #0F0;
    position: relative;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 1020px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mARcU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your images in span's with classes of Left, Center, Right instead of applying the class directly to the image.

```
<div class="Container">
  <span class="Left"><img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330"/></span>
  <span class="Center"><img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330"/></span>
  <span class="Right"><img src="images/flowers.png" width="330" height="330"/></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to set the container opacity, rather than the image. Try adding text to the Footer div and it should provide an effect. So use `.Footer img:hover{}` instead.
Also you can try updating your html and css to be a bit more efficient, and this may solve your issue.

replace your `<div id="header">` and `<div id="footer">` with `<header>` and `<footer>` tags. In your css you can then select which items you want to have a hover effect based on those tags.

For example, to hover the entire header and footer tags, or all elements of a type,

```
header:hover, footer:hover, .container:hover, img:hover{background-color:#f00;}
```

to hover selected elements of those containers

```
header img:hover{border:1px solid #f00;}
footer a:hover{color:#f00;}
.container img:hover{border:4px dotted #0f0;}
```

Hope this helps solve your issue.